# How to use reportlab SimpleDocTemplate with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, io, reportlab

I'm not able to output PDF with the following sample code

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

def get_table(self, response):
    buffer = StringIO()
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=letter)
    elements = []
    data= [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
           ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
           ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
           ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]
    t=Table(data)
    t.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.green),
                   ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.red)]))       
    elements.append(t)
    doc.build(elements)
    response.out.write(buffer.getvalue())
    buffer.close()
    return response
```

I'm using webapp2.RequestHandler and have set response header like so:

`self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=my.pdf'`

The result I'm getting is a blank pdf page.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The problem was that I was also calling

```
c = canvas.Canvas(self.response.out, pagesize=letter)
....
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

in the request handler. I didn't know you couldn't have both the

```
SimpleDocTemplate
```

as well as the

```
canvas.Canvas
```

Anyway it works now.